# Sms Notification from Android Apps

Tags: android, sms

we need to develop an android application for our customers .Our main objective is when the customer will place an order we should be notified on our mobile via SMS. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: For this, you will definetely need an SMS provider or a contract with a mobile provider.

Answer (score 1):

then try following method:

```
//---sends an SMS message to another device---
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
}
```

And call that method for an sms send:

```
sendSMS(“5556”, “Hello my friends!”);
```

(Of course, that would also mean you would have to pay the fees incurred in sending
all those SMS messages…)